# How do you play background music in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

All I want to do is play music in the background of the app, I don't want the music to continue when the app closes, kind of like a background music for a game.

Comment: So why not use AVAudioPlayer? Or (if the music is in the user's library) MPMusicPlayerController?

Answer (score 1):

```
AVAudioPlayer *sound1Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:YOUR_URL error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
if(!sound1Player)
   NSLog(@"error in play sound");
sound1Player.delegate=self;
sound1Player.numberOfLoops=0;
```

and make sure that you have `ON` the `Background Modes` in Project-->Capabilities
and also check(tick) the `Audio Mode` (see below picture)

[image]

Comment: So there are no compiler errors and no errors in the debug log, should I assume that it is the simulator?

Comment: @BrendanBallon not getting your point. what are you trying to say ?

Answer (score -2):

Use AVAudioPlayer to play the sound file from bundle and enable the background mode.

Closing/Killing the app will anyways stop the music.

Comment: Perhaps providing some code would be useful or at least a resource link?